# Using the <audio> tag with a ".ogg" mp3 stops in Chrome when I change tracks

Tags: html, google-chrome, audio

I'm using the following code to stream audio on a web page:

`<audio controls autoplay="autoplay"><source src="http://example:8001/mpd.ogg" type="audio/mp3">`

It works just well on Firefox, but on Chromium/Chrome it stops when I change the track.
So it's browser related, and doesn't have nothing to do with MPD itself.

Comment: Are you looking for alternatives, or reporting a bug? What is your actual question?

Comment: I'm looking for alternatives, as well for a solution to my problem.

Comment: See [this very old post regarding IceCast](http://icecast.imux.net/viewtopic.php?t=3969&postdays=0&postorder=asc&start=15&sid=867ed520d496735b56fbeb837d6daa89)

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `type="audio/mp3` to `type="audio/ogg`.

**Example -**

`<audio controls autoplay="autoplay"><source src="http://example:8001/mpd.ogg" type="audio/ogg">`